# wordpress plugin function wanted to call in standalone cron file

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I wanted to use wordpress 'tera wallet' plugin's functions in standalone cron file which is configured under cpanel -> Cron Jobs

php -q /home3/samadha1/xxxx.in/wp-content/plugins/woo-wallet/cfile.php

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has the own cron system.

For using cron by command line need to change wp-config.php :

1. Open your wp-config.php file
2. Go to the bottom of the database settings in wp-config.php. Add the code:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');
```

For scheduling your task need to use the function ["wp_schedule_event"](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/)

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpshout_plugin_activation' );

function wpshout_plugin_activation() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'wpshout_do_thing' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'wpshout_do_thing' );
    }
}
```

After this, you can add the cron command to "Cron Jobs":

```
php -q /home3/samadha1/xxxx.in/wp-cron.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just include `wp-load.php` from your your `cfile.php`.

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../wp-load.php';

// check if woo-wallet has been enabled 
if (!is_plugin_active('woo-wallet/woo-wallet.php')) {
  echo 'woo-wallet plugin is not active';
  exit(1);
}

// call any function of woo-wallet
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improve the long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.